# Difference between control and page view state

Tags: c#

What is the difference between a Control's and a Page's View State? If a Page View State is False then will the Control View State work? Can a child Control View State also work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [ASP.NET View State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386448(v=vs.100).aspx):

> Controls that use control state can require that view state be
>   encrypted by calling the RegisterRequiresViewStateEncryption method.
>   If any control in the page requires that view state be encrypted, all
>   view state in the page will be encrypted.

According to [Using Control State in ASP.NET 2.0](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15300/Using-Control-State-in-ASP-NET-2-0):

> Control state is a new construct within ASP.NET 2.0, and it is really
>   nothing more than view state; however, it is view state with a
>   significant advantage; that advantage is that other developers using
>   your control cannot disable control state as they can view state.

Comment: my Question is not about control state.My question about page view state and control view state.example gridview or repeater.if we page enableviewstate=false then gridview viewstate work or not.

Comment: @Mahe, with [that sort of edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3586582), you would be better to make your own answer.

Comment: @AsifIslam Yes It will work, enableviewstate=false does not affect gridview viewstate.

Answer (score 1):

Control State is similar to the ViewState. To answer your question, a control state is **independent** of the page ViewState. Asp.Net gives the permission to disable the page viewState. But, a control ViewState **cannot be disabled.**

- A control ViewState and Page View state are both stored as an hidden
  HTML input in a tag.
- If the page ViewState is disabled, then the control view state
  travels to the client page and back to the server.
- We cannot disable a control ViewState because, it is used to transfer
  critical information about the page.
- Yes, a control ViewState can be used to store the state of user
  controls. But, it is a good practice to limit the use of control
  state. A control View state should not be used as an alternative to page View state.

Additional Reading and References:

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1whwt1k7(v=vs.100).aspx
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstate(v=vs.110).aspx
3. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15300/Using-Control-State-in-ASP-NET-2-0
4. [ASP.NET: Why control state cannot be disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14640275/asp-net-why-control-state-cannot-be-disabled)

Answer (score 0):

ControlState is still available in case his the view state of hosting page is disabled.