# Issue related to EnableViewState Property in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate, page-lifecycle

I was reading article about EnableViewState property in ASP.NET.

Based on description written in article, once we set EnableViewState Property to false for particular control, then value of control will not be persist between page requests.

so i tried to add following code:

```
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtName" EnableViewState="false"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" />
```

and i added code in aspx.cs file as follows:

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
  txtName.Text = "Ghanshyam Thakkar";
```

now when i run an application, textbox will load the initial value `"Ghanshyam Thakkar"` now i click on submit button, value of textbox should get lost as i have set EnableViewState Property to false. but value is still there in textbox. why ? do i am missing anything to set ? please explain how to force page not to persist textbox value between page request.

Thanks,

Comment: If this not working then you can clear text after postback and also try autocomplete="off" for input control or form

Comment: try using ViewStateMode="disabled"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET: Why control state cannot be disabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14640275/asp-net-why-control-state-cannot-be-disabled)

Answer (score 0):

Even though `ViewState` is disabled for your `TextBox` control as you specified in your mark-up code, there is an additional item, known as "Control State", which [cannot be disabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1whwt1k7(v=vs.100).aspx) in the ASP.NET WebForms framework.